# Does Jupyter data path support unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, ipython, jupyter

Jupyter data path on my laptop includes unicode characters because my name has specific letters (\u00d6 and \u00fc) which are not available in plain Latin. I tried to change data path by changing JUPYTER_PATH variable but according to documentation it must include %APPDATA% variable and unfortunately %APPDATA% also includes the same letters. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: if the answer to the title is "yes" then why do you need to change anything?

Comment: I'm not sure if the answer is yes, cause it did not work at once. The only way I could find is the one below, if you have better solution, warmly welcome, I really appreciate to learn it.

Comment: specify what is the old path exactly (use `ascii()` function). What error do you see? What do you expect to happen instead? What is the new path (use `ascii()`)? What is your Windows ANSI codepage (`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`)? What is `chcp` (`cmd.exe` OEM encoding)?

Answer (score 1):

Well setting IPYTHONDIR variable to another location rather than the default one which also includes unicode characters, solved the problem, it is not an elegant solution in fact but it works.